# PHP: array of static classes results in "Use of undefined constant" warnings - is the "new" keyword an adequate solution?

Tags: php, static-classes

I have a couple of static classes, `TextAttributeType`, `NumberAttributeType` and `ColorAttributeType` that I want to put into an array, because I need the list of available types to be filterable/extensible later on.

When I try

```php
$available_attributes = array(
    TextAttributeType,
    NumberAttributeType,
    ColorAttributeType,
);
```

that results in the following Warning for each class name:

> **Warning:** Use of undefined constant TextAttributeType - assumed 'TextAttributeType'

It works when I add the `new` keyword in front of the class names:

```php
$available_attributes = array(
    new TextAttributeType,
    new NumberAttributeType,
    new ColorAttributeType,
);
```

- but doesn't that defy the use of static classes?

Comment: The _class_ is static?  Or the **methods** in the class are static?  May we see a small representation of your class declaration(s)?  Do you just want to store the class names as strings for later use?  I'm not sure I follow your use case.

Comment: I realize now that the term "static classes" is nonsense in a PHP context of course. What I meant is that the classes don't need a constructor and only have static methods. They are all extended from an abstract class `AttributeType`, but apart from implementing its abstrcact static method `::getLabel()` by returning a string with a human-readable name, not much is happening yet. I just want to define somehow "these types are available", and use `apply_filters()` in WordPress on that array. If using `new` despite only calling static methods is considered the "right" way, that's ok for me, too.

Answer (score 1):

In your second example you are instantiating the objects, if you only need an array of strings you could do:

```
$available_attributes = array(
  TextAttributeType::class,
  NumberAttributeType::class,
  ColorAttributeType::class,
```

);

From the php docs:
The special ::class constant allows for fully qualified class name resolution at compile time, this is useful for namespaced classes.

So you should get a string with the fully qualified name ( namespace + class name)

Comment: Interesting, though not what I had in mind. I think I'll go either for the class names as strings (I'm not using namespaces here, anyway) or using the new keyword. I find it quite odd that there's no way to reference a class that's already in scope directly...

Comment: Just wanted to add some functions that might be helpful: if u save an array of objects ( using the new keyword ) you can get the class of the object with the get_class function of php get_class($available_attributes[0]) for example, or check the type with instanceof ( if( $available_attributes[0] instanceof TextAttributeType) ) for example.